# rdflib.plugins.sparql not found?

Tags: python, sparql, attributeerror, rdflib

I am working through some basic rdflib stuff in python, trying to figure it out, and I am running into what seems like a basic problem.

The code is also [here](https://wiki.uib.no/info216/index.php/Python_Examples), the third example under Lecture 3: SPARQL.

```
import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("family.ttl", format='ttl')

q = rdflib.plugins.sparql.prepareQuery(
        """SELECT ?child ?sister WHERE {
                  ?child fam:hasParent ?parent .
                  ?parent fam:hasSister ?sister .
       }""",
       initNs = { "fam": "http://example.org/family#"})

sm = rdflib.URIRef("http://example.org/royal#SverreMagnus")

for row in g.query(q, initBindings={'child': sm}):
        print(row)
```

The family.ttl file is in the same directory and is as follows, as per the example.

```
@prefix rex: <http://example.org/royal#> .
@prefix fam: <http://example.org/family#> .

rex:IngridAlexandra fam:hasParent rex:HaakonMagnus .
rex:SverreMagnus fam:hasParent rex:HaakonMagnus .
rex:HaakonMagnus fam:hasParent rex:Harald .
rex:MarthaLouise fam:hasParent rex:Harald .
rex:HaakonMagnus fam:hasSister rex:MarthaLouise .
```

When I try to run this, I get an error.

```
AttributeError: module 'rdflib.plugins' has no attribute 'sparql'
```

Python is version 3.9.5, and rdflib is 6.0.1. Anyone know what the deal might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try changing your imports a bit, like this:

```py
import rdflib
from rdflib.plugins import sparql

g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("family.ttl")

q = sparql.prepareQuery(
    """SELECT ?child ?sister WHERE {
              ?child fam:hasParent ?parent .
              ?parent fam:hasSister ?sister .
   }""",
   initNs={"fam": "http://example.org/family#"})

sm = rdflib.URIRef("http://example.org/royal#SverreMagnus")

for row in g.query(q, initBindings={'child': sm}):
    print(row)
```